# Threejs - browser freezes when I load 80000 words what is the more efficient way of rendering plain 2d Text?

Tags: javascript, three.js, data-visualization

I tried to render 80,000 different words using WebGL specifically by three.js

however, once I try to render this amount of words,
my web browser was frozen.

Is there a better way to render a ton of words as 2D context?
I used an add-on of three.js called 'three-spritetext'

and how I added the words to be rendered is like below.

```
then((d) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {

        const SimpleText = new SpriteText(`${characters[i]}`, 5);
        SimpleText.color = 'orange';
        SimpleText.position.x = -200 + Math.random() * 10;
        SimpleText.position.y = 15 + Math.random() * 10
        lotsofText.push(SimpleText)

    }

})
```

To get the limit of the performance roughly,
I tried to scale down of the length of words to be rendered.

When I run this in my local host, it worked comparably okay when I went with length/3.

my sample code is here with the data.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/project/editor/AQOvpy

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since every sprite is rendered with a single draw call and `SpriteText` produces a canvas texture for each sprite, you have 80.000 draw calls and 80.000 textures in your app. It's not surprising that your browser freezes. I would say `SpriteText` is not usable for this number of sprites.

Comment: Check out [`CanvasTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture). You can write text to a canvas (although you'll probably have to do some logic for things like text-wrap, etc.), which can then be drawn as the texture of a simple single `PlaneGeometry` mesh.

Comment: @TheJim01thank you for your suggestion. So to draw that amount of text elements, I need to draw a dummy geometry like     

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube)

and the texture to be applied to the cube will be my 2d canvas having texts on it  like

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(bitmap)
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Google glyph sheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895385/1461008. Also https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/.